# Google Meta Bots

Tags: bots, meta-tags, googlebot

I have a question:

If I put this code in my website:

```
<META NAME="robot" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">
```

The google won't search the specific **page**, right? not all website.

Comment: Beware you use `NAME="robot"`  I believe this should be `NAME="robots"`  (plural).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With ***NOINDEX***, Google will not include any content from this page in its index (The page will be invisible to Google searches).

With ***NOFOLLOW***, Google bot will not try and follow any link on this page, hence these pages that the current page links to will not be included in Google index,  *unless* they can be reached (by Google bot) in other ways.

Beware that the snippet in the question uses the wrong name for this META tag.  `ROBOTS` needs to be in its plural form, not `ROBOT`.  While upper/lower/mixed casing doesn't matter, I do not believe the bots will try both names.

BTW, `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">` is equivalent to
          `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NONE">`

And, yes!  The rest of the web site will be indexed by Google as normally, unless of other bot exclusions.

The **official word** on the way Google bots interpret the META tags can be found
 on the [**Official Google WebMaster Central Blog**](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/03/using-robots-meta-tag.html)